# Remote Import Fonts with Gulp

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, clean-css, gulp-clean-css

So I'm noticing that my current Gulp setup isn't importing remote fonts such as google fonts. In my `main.scss` file I have:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,700,700italic,400italic,900,900italic);
```

And when it compiles minified it looks something like this:

```
@font-face{font-family:Lato;font-style:normal;font-weight:100;src:local('Lato Hairline'),local('Lato-Hairline'),url(../../fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/zJY4gsxBiSo5L7tNutxFNg.ttf) format('truetype')}
```

I'm using `gulp-minify-css` which uses clean-css. I know there may be something you have to do to get remote imports to work correctly but reading the docs left me with more questions then answers. Here is a section of my gulp file that handles the Sass/CSS minification:

```
// Minimize CSS
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/src/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCss({
        compatibility: 'ie8',
        aggressiveMerging: false
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: found solution for this?

Comment: @Abhishek nope, we've switched to `gulp-cssnano` since this post and have changed how we enqueue fonts so its no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is due to the lack of sass to import css files. You need to copy the css file and rename it to a *.scss file. The scss file can be imported correctly.

You will need to install and require gulp-rename: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename

In the case of your example you could also consider to user gulp-google-webfonts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-google-webfonts

fonts.list:

```
Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,700,700italic,400italic,900,900italic
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var googleWebFonts = require('gulp-google-webfonts');

var options = { };

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./fonts.list')
        .pipe(googleWebFonts(options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/fonts'))
        ;
    });

gulp.task('default', ['fonts']);
```

Comment: Thanks, we've changed how we manage fonts in projects now but `gulp-google-webfonts` will for sure be useful. Appreciate your answer.